# How To Encode HTTP parameters with Ruby and Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, encryption

I'm working on a Rails project with React for the frontend. I want to have some sort of encryption for parameters. For example:

```
  def index
    @foods = Food.page(secured_params(:page))
  end
```

secured_params() method is defined in the main ApplicationController of the application.

I want this encryption to be very simple and computational effective. In simple words, it doesn't cause much overhead. With the same technique, the React based frontend should be able to encrypt the parameters' values before they get sent to the backend. On the backend, when it receives the parameters' values, it decrypts and checks if the values are valid. If not, the backend just stops without doing anything. I'm using this technique to avoid bots/crawlers on the Internet.

Comment: How do you actually envisage this working?  If your actual client app works then why can't bots just do what your client app does?  You're going about this the wrong way.

Comment: @LukePark Hi, why not? Most bots are not smart. Unless they study my sites and then create bots specifically for it.

Comment: You need to edit your question to explain what exactly you are trying to prevent from happening.  Right now, I can't figure out what it is you are trying to prevent.

Comment: @LukePark I did Luke. at the end, I clearly say why i'm using this technique.

Comment: It really isn't that clear.  You also interchange the words encoding and encryption, which doesn't help, they're two very different things.  What are the bots doing that you are trying to prevent?  Why do you think encoding/encrypting the values will help?  How will your server determine if the values are "valid"?  Consider that if your client-side contains logic on encrypting then the bot can just duplicate this or literally submit the same data through your form...

Comment: @LukePark the comment you put is more like questioning the feasibility of this technique.

Comment: @LukePark Luke, look at what you are asking "How will your server determine if the values are "valid"?" that is my question. I need a technique (which I don't know for now) to resolve my issue and you are asking me. Also for duplication problems, you can put it as an answer. Then I should avoid. Right? Fair?

Comment: I'm trying to demonstrate to you that what you are asking is not possible...

Comment: You can use Cryto-JS to to use a wide variety of hashing algorithms from javascript. However since anything in javascript can be read by the client you cannot have a secret salt which makes it just security by obscurity. There are better ways like CAPTCHAS to foil bots anyways.

Comment: @LukePark Luke, it's an answer from your side. If you put it, I will also consider. There were nothing wrong with my question. You shouldn't decrease the score.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a similar thread on this: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/17259/better-techniques-than-url-parameter-encryption

In short, people have different techniques. Some do and the other don't follow this approach. If you are on the same side and want to do this, here is one of the approaches: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/63371